# Prevent Nuxt auth from redirecting on 400 status

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, jwt, nuxt.js

I have nuxt app where user the login/register in a form. i'm using nuxt auth module for the  authentification. the register form works fine. my only concern is when the user login, if he enters the wrong email or password in the first time he gets redirected to the home page. but whenever i go to the login page again without refreshing my app/browser, if he logs in with the wrong credentials he doesn't get redirect and everything works fine. So the problem is everytime i reload my browser/app , the first behavior is that he gets redirected to the home page , after that everything is fixed.

Here's my nuxt config file

```
export default {
    ssr: false,
    head: {
        titleTemplate: 'Lokazz',
        title: 'Lokazz',
        meta: [
            { charset: 'utf-8' },
            {
                name: 'viewport',
                content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'
            },
            {
                hid: 'description',
                name: 'description',
                content:
                    'Martfury - Multipurpose Marketplace Vuejs Ecommerce Template'
            }
        ],
        link: [
            {
                rel: 'stylesheet',
                href:
                    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,400,500,600,700&amp;amp;subset=latin-ext'
            }
        ]
    },

    css: [
        'swiper/dist/css/swiper.css',
        '~/static/fonts/Linearicons/Font/demo-files/demo.css',
        '~/static/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
        '~/static/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        '~/assets/scss/style.scss'
    ],

    plugins: [
        { src: '~plugins/vueliate.js', ssr: false },
        { src: '~/plugins/swiper-plugin.js', ssr: false },
        { src: '~/plugins/vue-notification.js', ssr: false },
        { src: '~/plugins/lazyLoad.js', ssr: false },
    ],

    

    buildModules: [
        '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
        '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
    ],

    styleResources: {
        scss: './assets/scss/env.scss'
    },

    modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios', 'nuxt-i18n','vue-sweetalert2/nuxt', '@nuxtjs/auth-next'],

    i18n: {
        locales: [
            { code: 'en', file: 'en.json' },
            { code: 'fr', file: 'fr.json' }
        ],
        lazy: true,
        defaultLocale: 'en',
        langDir: 'lang/locales/'
    },

    router: {
        linkActiveClass: '',
        linkExactActiveClass: 'active'
    },

    server: {
        port: 4002,
        host: 'localhost'
    },
    auth: {
        strategies: {
          local: {
              token: {
              property: 'token',
              global: true,
              // required: true,
              // type: 'Bearer'
            },
            user: {
              property: 'user',
              autoFetch: false
            },
            endpoints: {
              login: { url: 'http://localhost:5000/login', method: 'post' },
              logout: { url: '/api/auth/logout', method: 'post' },
              user: { url: '/api/auth/user', method: 'get', }
            }
          }
        }
      }
};
```

my login component

```
<template lang="html">
    <form @submit.prevent="loginAuth">
        <div class="ps-form__content">
            <h5>Accéder á votre compte</h5>
            <ul>
                <li style="color:red" v-for="(error, index) in errors" :key="index">
                {{ error }}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="form-group">
                <v-text-field
                    v-model="login.email"
                    class="ps-text-field"
                    :error-messages="emailErrors"
                    @input="$v.email.$touch()"
                    placeholder="Tapez votre email"
                    height="50"
                    outlined
                />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <v-text-field
                    v-model="login.password"
                    type="password"
                    class="ps-text-field"
                    :error-messages="passwordErrors"
                    @input="$v.password.$touch()"
                    placeholder="Tapez votre mot de passe"
                    height="50"
                    outlined
                />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button
                    type="submit"
                    class="ps-btn ps-btn--fullwidth mt-2" @click.prevent="loginAuth"  >
                    Loginnnnn
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ps-form__footer">
            <router-link class="registerLink" to="/account/register">
                   Don't have an account? Register
            </router-link>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
import { email, required } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';
import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate';
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
    name: 'Login',

    data() {
        return {
            errors: [],
            login: {
                email: null,
                password: null,
            }
        };
    },
    computed: {
        emailErrors() {
            const errors = [];
            if (!this.$v.email.$dirty) return errors;
            !this.$v.email.required && errors.push('This field is required');
            return errors;
        },
        passwordErrors() {
            const errors = [];
            if (!this.$v.password.$dirty) return errors;
            !this.$v.password.required && errors.push('This field is required');
            return errors;
        },
    },
    validations: {
        email: { required },
        password: { required }
    },
    methods: {
        async loginAuth(e) {
            try {
                let response = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', { data: this.login })
                console.log(response)
            } catch (err) {
                // this.errors = err.response.data
                console.log(err.response)
            }
        },
    }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

.registerLink {
    color:#1976d2;
}

</style>
```

Comment: What if you add `auth: false` to your login component?

Comment: Btw `ssr: false` is deprecated. You should use `mode: client` nowadays.

Comment: didn't work.... i've spent the whole day with it , please help !!!

Comment: Still not sure about the actual issue. Can you explain it a bit better please?

Comment: When i click the login button , if there's an error i get redirected to the home page and i don't that to happen. instead i want to show the error ( incorrect password for eg or wrong email ) i receive from the backend

Comment: I'm not sure why you got redirected? Are you seeing your `console.log` at least? Try to double-check that everything is fine with the vue devtools and in the network.

Answer (score 0):

I do have this kind of additional configuration my `auth` module

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
auth: {
  redirect: {
    login: '/login',
    home: '/',
    logout: '/login',
    callback: false,
  },
}
```

Still, you'll need to debug it a bit more here IMO.

Oh and don't forget to pass the `auth` as a global middleware too

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
router: {
  middleware: ['auth'],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the problem. it was due to the user fetch property. since i was sending the user information back in a proper way the call resulted in an error that automatically did redirect to callback url.